# How to make ifcfg script "run" the exact commands I need?

Tags: networking, fedora, routing, ifconfig

On a fresh Fedora 24 install, I want to disable NetworkManager since I 
have a static IP and hate daemons.

If I do this after startup (as root), everything works fine:

```
ifconfig enp1s0 192.168.0.3 netmask 255.255.0.0 
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

What's the equivalent /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp1s0 
files? Following 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432620/how-to-setup-static-ip-in-fedora-19 
(which I realize is Fedora 19, not 24, but probably should work 
anyway), I did:

```
DEVICE="enp1s0" 
NM_CONTROLLED="no" 
NAME=enp1s0 
ONBOOT=yes 
TYPE=Ethernet 
BOOTPROTO=none 
DEFROUTE=yes 
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
IPADDR=192.168.0.3 
NETMASK=255.255.0.0 
BROADCAST=192.168.255.255 
PEERDNS=yes 
PEERROUTES=yes 
IPV6INIT=no 
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes 
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes 
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes 
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes 
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy 
UUID=[masked though unlikely private] 
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
```

but this doesn't work. If I reboot with the above, I get "network is 
unreachable".

I realize I could simply run my commands in a startup script, but am 
trying to do things the "right way" for now.

Comment: To delete all this fluff in Ubuntu/Debian I usually uninstall `resolvconf` and the package dependencies system pretty much take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora documentation says that `NetworkManager` is a default network daemon since Fedora 20. Most probably you should say sorry to it and get used to it.

However, you should still be able to use `network` daemon. Test it via command line:

```
systemctl start/stop/restart/status network
```

If it brings up network for you, enable it:

```
systemctl enable network
```

Although, as mentioned before, Network Manager  is meant to handle your networks and network is more as a helper. Take a look [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/Networking_Guide/sec-NetworkManager_and_the_Network_Scripts.html).

Comment: I'm trying to bring up a minimal Fedora 24 system, and believe static networks don't need daemons! I should point out that it ran by default, but I'm basically trying to kill as many daemons/processes as necessary :)

Comment: @barrycarter, I might used wrong words. Network service (not to use a daemon word) is responsible for bringing up network interfaces. I don't know fedora very well but RedHat, CentOS or Debian does not create any program that runs in the background. Network is only a script run on boot/shutdown that is responsible for bringing up a network. After it finishes it's work, nothing is left in background to watch status of network. Take a look what it does in **start** section at `/etc/init.d/network`.

Answer (score 1):

Distable the `network-manager`:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Start and enable `network.service`:

```
systemctl restart network.service
systemctl enable network.service
```

Edit you `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp1s0` change:

```
BOOTPROTO=none 
PEERDNS=yes
```

To:

```
BOOTPROTO="static"
PEERDNS=no
```

Configure your `/etc/resolv.conf` then apply changes:

```
systemctl restart network.service
```